# Symfony2 - LswMemcacheBundle - Can i use memecache.default service inside another service?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, memcached

i have declared a service with some dependence in service.yml, e.g:

```
content_helper:
    class:        Oilproject\ContentBundle\Helper\ContentHelper
    arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@memcache.default"]
    calls:
                - [setMemcache, ["@memcache.default"]]
```

My Helper class:

```
private $em;

    private $memcache;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->memcache = $memcache;
    }

    public function setMemcache($memcache) {
        $this->memcache = $memcache;

        return $this;
    }
//...
```

But when i call

```
$memcache = $this->memcache;
$contents = $memcache->get($key);
```

This return

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use setter injection **and** constructor injection at the same time.

Further you forgot to add memcache aka a second expected argument to the constructor.
With your current constructor injection implementation `$this->memcache` will always be `null` / a `non-object` as the exception states after the object/service has been created.

Try this:

**configuration:**

```
content_helper:
    class:        Vendor\Your\Service\TheClass
    arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@memcache.default"]
```

**class**

```
private $em;
private $memcache;

public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $memcache) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->memcache = $memcache;
}

// example usage
public function someFunction()
{
    return $this->memcache->get('key');
}
```

Make sure when instanciating your newly created service you either inject it into the other service where you want to use it or get it from the container there. Otherwise the memcache service won't be injected. Example:

```
 // getting i.e. inside a controller with access to the container
 $value = $this->container->get('content_helper')->someFunction();
```